# Is there a more elegant way to do the following in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to avoid warnings about a comparison between unsigned int and signed int.

I use loops such as:

```
for (int i =0 ; i < vec.size(); i++) {
 // do something
}
```

which gives these warnings (which by itself is fine, I want high-level of warnings).

I thought of changing it to the following:

```
for (auto i = vec.size()*0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
 // do something
}
```

in which case I don't get the warnings. But I am wondering if there is something more elegant than that, that would automatically deduce the type required for the iterator.

Comment: Use the `range for` construct. `for ( auto const& v : vec ) {}`.

Comment: `decltype` will let you automatically deduce a type based on a value.

Comment: There's `for (decltype(vec.size()) i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i)`, which more directly expresses your sentiment, but I am pretty sure I wouldn't call it more elegant :)

Comment: http://herbsutter.com/2015/01/14/reader-qa-auto-and-for-loop-index-variables/

Answer (score 8):

Use range-based for loop

```
for (auto& i : vec)
{
    cout << *i;
}
```

Use iterators.

```
for (auto it = vec.begin(), end_it = vec.end(); it != end_it; ++it)
{
    cout << *it;
}
```

If you want a counter, use `std::vector<T>::size_type` or just `size_t` if you're lazy.

Comment: I wouldn't say using `size_t` is lazy. The only time you really want to use `size_type` is for generic programming, when the container is a template type. The rest of the time you know that `size_type` is `size_t`, but `size_t` is a lot cleaner to write.

Comment: `end_it = vec.end()` is pretty an unnecessary premature optimization IMO, which I don't mind at all except when it degrades the simplicity/readability of the code.

Comment: It's a habit, a habit I'm used to and I intend to keep :)

Answer (score 1):

If that's an option, prefer Standard Library higher-order primitives from `<algorithm>`, such as (not limited to):

- `std::accumulate`
- `std::copy`
- `std::transform`

They are very expressive when used with lambdas. Only use `for` when that's not an option, and prefer range-for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Or even a descending loop:

```
auto i = vec.size();
while (i --> 0)
   // ...
```

Comment: how about `for(auto i = vec.size(); i --> 0;)` Nothing like using `-->` to make people relatively new to C++ say "wtf?". Also most people are going to say it's awful, don't do it.

Comment: @Dave works the same, but I'd prefer `while` because you'd say "while x goes to zero".

Comment: Well you can write any for loop as a while loop. Do you never write for loops? For that matter you can write any while loop with goto. It's all syntactic sugar. I write this, but I agree with you, "while" is the only one which reads correctly in english.

Comment: @Dave I have not said you must use `while`. I just find it more "appropriate"; ymmv.

Answer (score -1):

Because question starts with a phrase:

> "I want to avoid warnings about a comparison between unsigned int and
>   signed int"

I have assumed that `vec.size()` returns `unsigned int`.

If type returned by `vec.size()` can be stored in `unsigned int` then you can use following.

```
for (auto i = 0u; i < vec.size(); i++) {
       // do something
}
```

Otherwise use appropriate type or check other answers.

If `vec` is of type `std::vector<T>` (which was not mentioned in question, hence above code) you can also use for_each loop (which also was not mentioned)

```
std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](T t){ /* do something with t */ });
std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](T & t){ /* do something with t */});
std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](const T & t){ /* do something with t */ });
```

It can be more handy if you have to walk over vector elements with some already existing function-objects (or methods, or non-member functions)

```
void f(int x) { std::cout << "f: " << x << "\n"; }
void g(int x) { std::cout << "g: " << x << "\n"; }
...
std::vector<int> vec{1, 2, 3};
std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::bind(f, std::placeholders::_1)); //calls f(int)
std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::bind(g, std::placeholders::_1)); //calls g(int)
```

More handy, becasue you can keep fancy callback and set it to appropriate function according to need

```
std::function<void(int)> callback = std::bind(f, std::placeholders::_1);
if (userWantsG())
   callback = std::bind(g, std::placeholders::_1);
std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), callback); //calls g or f
```

Comment: That will go horribly wrong if the size is too large for `unsigned int`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour the question does not say what is returned by `vec.size()`. It's only asking how to avoid warnings about a comparison between unsigned int and signed int.

Comment: It's reasonable to assume that `vec.size()` is `std::vector<T>::size`

Comment: @doc: OK, if it's not actually a `std::vector`, but something documented to have a size constrained by size of `unsigned int`, then it's just subtly dangerous, not outright wrong.

Comment: Then `for (int i =0 ; i < vec.size(); i++)` in OPs question may also be too small to hold `std::size_t`.

Comment: @doc: Indeed. Which is why a good answer should explain how to do it properly, not just how to avoid the warning.

Comment: @MikeSeymour O.K. I have edited answer. However if question starts with `"I want to avoid warnings about a comparison between unsigned int and signed int"` then it's not so clear for me that OP asks for iterating over `std::vector`.

Comment: This literally saves 1 character over writing `size_t i = 0` which is actually correct and not borderline correct.

Comment: @Dave literally it should be `std::size_t`. I'm referring to OPs loop, which uses `auto` (`auto i = vec.size()*0` if you can see) It's also not clear that `vec.size()` returns `std::size_t`

Comment: literally you don't need the `std::`, you're guaranteed not to need it. Thanks `C`. I don't want to look up the quote right now but I'm pretty sure it's a guarantee if you use the default allocator `size_type` is `size_t`. If it's not, you can act like it is because 100% of implementations do it.

Comment: @Dave I mean the type of `vec` was not mentioned in question.